# Change value/move slider while pressing left/right arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, slider

It's about changing strap in slider and value while left or right arrows are pressed.

I need to create application with slider (in Visual Studio and Eclipse[swing]) that could change value in slider by pressing arrow(left and right).

How do I construct method/loop that can change location of zipper in slider. I know that for example this should look like this:

```
while right arrow is pressing then sliderlocation and value += 1
```

But, the second question is how to set speed of changing this object.

Have anyone idea how can I make it?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Look into using a Key Bindings. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: @Trobbins don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. The Swing tutorial you referenced has a section on `Key Bindings`.

Comment: What you ask is the default; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your approach.